# Fabric - Unable to complete settings download

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am integrating Twitter in my iOS app using the Fabric app. I've followed all the steps but the process is stuck in the "Verifying installation phase".
I can see this error in the Xcode console log:

> [Fabric] Unable to complete settings download Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x7fac0ac1d1a0
>   {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/com.xxxxx.yyyyy/settings,
>   NSUserStringVariant=(
>           Move
>       ), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/448B0F63-C299-46E5-B455-D4666610023E/data/Containers/Data/Application/F3B667A7-4937-4040-93BD-7727F433E2B2/Library/Caches/io.fabric.sdk.ios.data/com.xxxxx.yyyyy/settings.json,
>   NSFilePath=/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/com.xxxxx.yyyyy/settings,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7fac0ac1c3a0 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   No such file or directory"}
>
> [Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7fac0ac1d1a0
>   {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/com.xxxxx.yyyyy/settings,
>   NSUserStringVariant=(
>           Move
>       ), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/448B0F63-C299-46E5-B455-D4666610023E/data/Containers/Data/Application/F3B667A7-4937-4040-93BD-7727F433E2B2/Library/Caches/io.fabric.sdk.ios.data/com.xxxxx.yyyyy/settings.json,
>   NSFilePath=/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/com.xxxxx.yyyyy/settings,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7fac0ac1c3a0 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   No such file or directory"}

I've already Googled a lot, restarting and so on... but nothing worked.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has been solved removing another crash reporting tools (AppPulse) that still was in the app.